# I can't seem to grasp the basics behind less than and more than operators, could someone identify where I'm going wrong?

Tags: c++

So the only issue I can find with the program below is that I've messed up the >< to check the income tax rates. What have I done wrong?
The rest of the program runs as intended with the calculations all working the only issue is, as mentioned, my use of the less than and more than to find the correct tax bracket.
For example; if I used the yearly earnings of 46000 (Which places it into the second tax bracket) it will run the first tax bracket instead meaning it only gets reduced by 20% not 40%.

```
//Program
cout << "This program will help organize your finances. \n";
cout << "How much do you earn a year? \n";
cin >> finances;

//Selecting Income Tax Rate
if (finances <= 11500) {
    cout << "On your current salary, no income tax will be paid \n";
    monthlyPay = (finances / 12);
    cout << "This means you are paid " << monthlyPay << " a month after tax. \n";
}
else if (finances >= 11501 || finances <= 45000) {
    cout << "On your current salary, you will need to commit 20% of income to pay income tax. \n";
    rateReduction = finances * basicRate;
    taxFreeFinances = finances - rateReduction;
    monthlyPay = taxFreeFinances / 12;
    cout << "This means you are paid " << monthlyPay << " a month after tax. \n";
}
else if (finances >= 45001 || finances <= 150000) {
    cout << "On your current salary, you will need to commit 20% of income to pay income tax. \n";
    rateReduction = finances * higherRate;
    taxFreeFinances = finances - rateReduction;
    monthlyPay = taxFreeFinances / 12;
    cout << "This means you are paid " << monthlyPay << " a month after tax. \n";
}
else if (finances > 15000) {
    cout << "On your current salary, you will need to commit 20% of income to pay income tax. \n";
    rateReduction = finances * addRate;
    taxFreeFinances = finances - rateReduction;
    monthlyPay = taxFreeFinances / 12;
    cout << "This means you are paid " << monthlyPay << " a month after tax. \n";
}
else {
    cout << "You have typed in a value other than a number. Program closing. \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `else if (finances >= 45001 || finances <= 150000) ` You're using `||` when you want `&&`

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for that, I'm a real idiot!

Comment: and i think you missed this thing out as well, `else if (finances > 15000) {` which supposed to be `else if (finances > 150000) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

`||` is `OR`. You actually meant to use `AND`: `&&`, didn't you?

Also seems like you have a typo in the last one. 15000? or 150000?

Comment: Totally missed the typo actually! Thanks!

Comment: The first half of the check is redundant anyway, it could just be `else if ( finances <= 45000 )` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 else if (finances >= 11501 || finances <= 45000) {
```

Every number is greater than or equal to 11,501 or less than or equal to 45,000. There is no number for which that is not true.

10 is less than 45,000. 12,000 is less than or equal to 45,000. 80,000 is greater than or equal to 11,501. So that test catches *every* number.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed to change || to && didn't I? Thanks :D

Comment: What if `finances` is NaN ;)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh I need to work on so much! Thankfully this is only a side project and not my college work

Comment: @MFisherKDX: He said every number. NaN is not one, hence the name.

Comment: You two are too much.